# GAE How to call doGet-Method with HttpClient

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I want to return myHighscores from Datastore:
i.e.: Paul,1200
      Tom,1000
      Kevin,800

```
private void returnHighscores(HttpServletResponse resp, String game, int max) throws IOException {
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Key gameKey = KeyFactory.createKey("game", game);
    Query query = new Query("highscore", gameKey);
    query.addSort("points", Query.SortDirection.DESCENDING);
    List<Entity> highscores = datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(max));

    for(Entity e : highscores) {
        resp.getWriter().println(e.getProperty("name") + "," + e.getProperty("points"));
    }
}
```

But if I try to run this i get an Error:

> com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found. The suggested index for this query is:

```html
 <datastore-index kind="highscore" ancestor="true" source="manual"> <property name="points" direction="desc"/> </datastore-index>
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: so, do you get any exception? is your code failing? or what issue do you have?

Comment: when i manually try to call the method with this URL:
mueckenfang-986.appspot.com/------------?/game=mueckenfang&name=Paul&points=1200&max=10

i dont know what to write before of the "?"
In the book i am working with there is an identifier like "myserver?" or some

Comment: I get this error when i try a URL like:
mueckenfang-986.appspot.com/mueckenfang
The requested URL /mueckenfang was not found on this server.

Do i need a dyndns or stuff?

Comment: Or do I need to us ....appspot.com/hello
and work with the doPost Method

Comment: did you map your servlet to an url in your `web.xml`?

Comment: please update your question with your web.xml and the errors you are getting.

Comment: I fixed it my self! But i have another question ( edited Question again..)